# how can find out how many BroadcastReceiver registered on the phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm on sms application that should find out how many sms receivers registers in user phone. I googled and find this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) but it seems that you can just get your package receivers with:

```
  List<ResolveInfo> myList = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(i,0);
```

Comment: AFAIK, that should still return all matching Receivers, not just your package's. How are you constructing the `Intent`?

Comment: @mike just new intent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Intent` you pass in the `queryBroadcastReceivers()` call needs to match up with the `<intent-filter>` of the Receivers you're looking for. In your case, you simply need to create the `Intent` with the `SMS_RECEIVED` action.

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```